# How to remove one-page menu option from education base theme WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove on-page menu option from front page in Acme themes (Education base) WordPress theme. I have remove option from function.php but its not working. what more steps I need to do for normal/primary-menu option on home/front page.

[removed one page menu option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYksE.jpg)

Comment: Please add your code to your answer (not a screenshot) and format it properly. Doing this, everyone can see it clearly, debugging it and helping you finding a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
function wp_sns_remove_menu_items() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ):
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
    endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wp_sns_remove_menu_items' );
```